# Categorization of Bugs in JIRA

Tags: jira, issue-tracking

We use JIRA to track bugs in our application. Our software pipeline is agile base 2 weeks sprint cycle. Here is the approach that we are thinking about categorizing our bugs, to better understand their nature and magnitude.

---

For bugs we use the following keywords in "Issue Type" field of Jira.

- Production Bug (Found in Production)
- Backlog Bug (Came out during Sprint cycle - QA)

Extra field in JIRA, called "Bug category", with the following keywords, to further categorize above bugs.

1. Functional Bug (Functionality not working as it is,suppose to be ... due to missed requirement, coding flaw, or missed QA).
2. Regression Bug (Impact of new rolled out feature)
3. Data Problem (Bad migration, corruption due to bug, etc)
4. Environmental Issue (Windows Vs Linux, etc)

Your thoughts will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of this categories? do you plan to filter by it? issue separated reports? have different workflows?

Comment: Just to filter issues by these categories to generate views, reports, etc

Comment: How about just using labels then? they are just as easy to filter by.

Comment: @yossiz74 labels can't be modified as part of a bulk change

Comment: Have you considered adding a select menu with the choices?

Comment: @kdopen Which JIRA version are you using? I have 6.4.12 and there is no problem editing/adding/removing labels in bulk

Comment: @yossiz74 6.3.9 - to date any bulk change to labels was complete replacement, which meant you couldn't just add 1 label to 200 issues with a mix of existing ones. Now I see from https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-24118?focusedCommentId=751200&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-751200 that 6.4 finally fixes that

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. Labels are definitely good option to filter the issues. The reason for adding a specific field is to make it mandatory to be filled, and with only specific keywords, so that we have better control over them. Technically, it all sounds good, however it I am really looking for input regarding the classification of bugs, based on your experience.